# Do I have to use an ISP-provided VDSL modem?

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, isp

Each ISP so far has provided me with their own tweaked VDSL2+ modem. My current provider installed an VDSL modem that had so many errors that I considered paying the additional penalty for changing providers within a year. Knowing that the competition isn't really better I stayed with them, also because I found a solution in buying a proper router and only created a bridge with the modem.

Soon I will be moving house and I am considering my option for ISPs. Still all come with their own tweaked version of a small set of modems. There isn't really much to choose from in terms of modems.

The question is if I do need to accept the ISP provided modem, or could I just throw their crappy modems away and buy a very simple modem that would act as the entry point giving all home network management to my fancy router?

Comment: Adding your country may help in this case, as the answer may depend on local customs.  I'm in the USA and have a cable provider that charges $7/month for a modem provided by them, however you can supply your own instead and it is VERY worth it to do so.

Comment: @Tyson Well, telling by the avatar I think he is from Antwerp, Belgium. ;) http://superuser.com/users/73837/andra

Comment: No, but you do need information from your ISP in order to use a modem that they don't provide (specifically the VPI/VCI) so that the modem can talk properly with the DSLAM on the other end. You should be able to get these from your current modem if you can log into it. If the modem is routed, you'll also need to know your layer 3 settings to program into it so that you have a proper route for packets leaving the device.